# Conditional expectation of standard normal variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

Let $X, Y$ be independent and identically distributed standard normal variables, with $aX+bY=u,$ what is $E\left[ cX+dY\frac{b}{\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}\frac {e^{itx}}{b^2 +(x-a)^2}\,\mathrm dxaX+bY=u\right]$? With $a,b,c,d,u$ fixed.

Currently what I have is:

\begin{align}
& E[cX+dY\mid aX+bY=u] \\[10pt]
= {} & cE\left[X\frac{b}{\pi} \int_{\Bbb R}\frac {e^{itx}}{b^2 +(x-a)^2}\,\mathrm dxaX+bY=u\right]+dE\left[Y\frac{b}{\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}\frac {e^{itx}}{b^2 +(x-a)^2}\,\mathrm dxaX+bY=u\right]
\end{align}

and as $aX+bY=u$, then $X=\frac{u-bY}{a}$,$Y=\frac{u-aX}{b}$
So we have:
$$cE\left[ X\frac{b}{\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}\frac {e^{itx}}{b^2 +(x-a)^2}\,\mathrm dxaX+bY=u \right] + dE \left[ Y\frac{b}{\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}\frac {e^{itx}}{b^2 +(x-a)^2}\,\mathrm dxaX+bY=u\right] = cE\left[\frac{u-bY}{a}\right] + dE\left[\frac{u-aX}{b}\right]$$
and as $E[X]=E[Y]=0$, we get
$$u\left(\frac{c}{a}+\frac{d}{b}\right)$$
is that correct?

Comment: If $X,Y$ are iid normal, then the event $\{aX+bY=u\}$ has zero probability, and then the expectation conditioned on this event is undefined.

Comment: @ChargeShivers It's perfectly well defined in this context. It's just the expectation with respect to the conditional density. And the conditional density is just $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that:
$$(a^2+b^2)(cX+dY)=(ac+db)(aX+bY)+(bc-ad)(bX-aY)$$

So setting $U=aX+bY$ and $V=bX-aY$ we can write:$$cX+dY=\frac{(ac+db)U+(bc-ad)V}{a^2+b^2}$$ It is not difficult to find that: $$\mathsf{Cov}(U,V)=0$$ Because we are dealing with normal distribution this is sufficient for independence of $U$ and $V$.

Further we have $\mathbb EV=0$ and this together leads to:

$$\mathbb E(cX+dY\mid U=u)=\frac{(ac+db)u}{a^2+b^2}$$